# NodeJs obtener el valor de una funcion en una varibale

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Hola tengo la siguiente linea de código

```
 var subsn = 'https://miapp.miapp.com/get-client-subscription/'+id_client;
const checknsubs =  request(subsn, function (error, response, body) {

    var obj = JSON.parse(body);
   console.log(obj.length);
   return obj.length
});

//const userConditions = await pool.query('');

   console.log(checknsubs);
```

Mi problema es que cuando trato de imprimir en consola **checknsubs**  me tira un objeto vacio creo o simplemente no me tira nada en terminal pero si imprimo **obj.length** dentro de la función , que según yo es lo que estoy intentando regresar, pues si me da el tamaño de los objetos que hay dentro  del json de respuesta. Alguien me puede decir como sacar este valor? en total el json cuenta con 5 objetos dentro de si, entonces  `console.log(obj.length)` me da `5`, necesito ese 5 en **checknsubs**

Comment: Sucede que el método `request()` que estás usando es asíncrono, por lo tanto, sólo podrías capturar el valor, bien dentro de la función `callback` que le estás pasando o bien implementando `async/await`. Saludos

Answer (score 2):

`request` realiza una petición asíncrona al servidor, entre las distintas posibilidades que existen en js, utiliza un callback para retornar la respuesta, para hacerlo con una sintaxis parecida a la que quieres, tendrías que crear una promesa y hacer un `await`, pero en ese caso tendrías que hacer todo dentro de una función `async`.

```
var request = require('request');

var subsn = 'https://miapp.miapp.com/get-client-subscription/'+id_client;

(async () => {

    const checknsubs = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request(subsn, function (error, response, body) {
            resolve(response);
        });
    });

    console.log(checknsubs);

})();
```

[request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#promises--asyncawait) no retorna una promesa, sino se podŕía hacer directamente, hay otras librerías que usan promesas como [request-promise](https://github.com/request/request-promise).

Comment: como puedo asignar todo a una variable? todo de checknsubs hacia otra variable, lo que necesito es gurdar todo el **body.length** de la respuesta como una cadena

Comment: hola creo que no me di a entender, el problema no es obtener el length del body, la cuestión es que quiero imprimirlo u obtener ese valor fuera de la funcion y dentro de una variable.

Comment: Si, entendí, y lo mas cercano a lo que quieres es esto, usando `request` no hay otra solución que deje afuera totalmente la variable, a menos que pongas un timeout o algo asi, pero no es una buena práctica. Otro tema es que body tendría que ser un json y transformado un array, pero supongo que no tienes problemas con eso.

Answer (score 0):

De esta manera puedes obtener el resultado que necesitas

```
const express = require('express')
const rp = require('request-promise')
const app = express()

app.get('/:id_client', (req, res) => {
  rp({
    uri: 'https://miapp.miapp.com/get-client-subscription/',
    qs: {q: req.params.id_client},
    json: true
  })
    .then((data) => {      
      console.log(data)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)      
    })
})
```